# How do I specify num_test_nets in restart?

Tags: caffe

I trained a GoogleNet model for a while, and now I'd like to restart from a checkpoint, adding a test phase.  I have the test already in my train_val.prototxt file, and I added the proper parameters to my solver.prototxt ... but I get an error on the restart:

```
I0712 15:53:02.615947 47646 net.cpp:278] This network produces output loss2/loss1
I0712 15:53:02.615964 47646 net.cpp:278] This network produces output loss3/loss3
I0712 15:53:02.616109 47646 net.cpp:292] Network initialization done.
F0712 15:53:02.616665 47646 solver.cpp:128] Check failed: param_.test_iter_size() == num_test_nets (1 vs. 0) test_iter must be specified for each test network.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f550cf70e6d  (unknown)
    @     0x7f550cf72ced  (unknown)
    @     0x7f550cf70a5c  (unknown)
    @     0x7f550cf7363e  (unknown)
    @     0x7f550d3b605b  caffe::Solver<>::InitTestNets()
    @     0x7f550d3b63ed  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f550d3b6738  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @     0x7f550d4fa633  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
    @     0x7f550da5bb76  caffe::SolverRegistry<>::CreateSolver()
    @     0x7f550da548f4  train()
    @     0x7f550da52316  main
    @     0x7f5508f43b15  __libc_start_main
    @     0x7f550da52d3d  (unknown)
```

solver.prototxt

```
train_net: "<my_path>/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 4000
test_initialization: false
display: 40
average_loss: 40
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
stepsize: 320000
gamma: 0.96
max_iter: 10000000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0002
snapshot: 40000 
snapshot_prefix: "models/<my_path>"
solver_mode: CPU
```

train_val.prototxt train and test layers:

```
name: "GoogleNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 224
    mean_value: 104
    mean_value: 117
    mean_value: 123
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/<blah>/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 224
    mean_value: 104
    mean_value: 117
    mean_value: 123
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/<blah>/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should modify one place in your solver.prototxt from

```
train_net: "/train_val.prototxt"
```

to

```
net: "/train_val.prototxt"
```

Because the [Solver](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/solver.cpp) does not use value of "train_net" to initialize a test net, so the test phase you added was not founded by the solver.

In fact, the parameters "train_net" and "test_net" are separately used to initialize a train net and a test net only, while "net" is used for both.